# How to map an array within an array and achieve the following output?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

In the given input,

```
{
    "editable": true,
    "sections": [
        {
            "title": "Identification",
            "calingaKey": "",
            "content": [
                [{
                    "name": "Classification",
                    "text": "Product",
                    "url": "",
                    "info": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "Product Number",
                    "text": "####1234",
                    "url": "",
                    "info": ""
                }]
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Position and Contact",
            "calingaKey": "",
            "content": [
                [{
                    "name": "Manufacturer",
                    "text": "Value of Manufacturer",
                    "url": "",
                    "info": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "Hardware Version",
                    "text": "####1234",
                    "url": "",
                    "info": ""
                }]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

"content" is an array of array of objects. Basically, the "name" field has to be replaced by values stored in their corresponding keys in the "calinga" variable.

I could do it for the "title" field, but each "name" field should also be replaced by it's name in the variable.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var calinga = {
    "Identification": "Identifikation",
    "Position and Contact": "Positions und Contacts",
    "Classification": "Classifikation",
    "Product Number": "Produkt Number",
    "Manufacturer": "Manufakturer",
    "Hardware Version": "Hware Vsion"
}
---
{
"editable": payload.editable,
"sections": payload.sections map(item01, index01)->{
    "title": calinga[item01.title],
    "content": item01.content map(item02)->(item02)
}
}
```

How Can I achieve the following output?

```
{
    "editable": true,
    "sections": [
        {
            "title": "Identifikation",
            "calingaKey": "",
            "content": [
                [{
                    "name": "Classifikation",
                    "text": "Product",
                    "url": "",
                    "info": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "Produkt Number",
                    "text": "####1234",
                    "url": "",
                    "info": ""
                }]
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Positions und Contacts",
            "calingaKey": "",
            "content": [
                [{
                    "name": "Manufakturer",
                    "text": "Value of Manufacturer",
                    "url": "",
                    "info": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "Hware Vsion",
                    "text": "####1234",
                    "url": "",
                    "info": ""
                }]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mapObject() once you descend from the last nested array into objects. Then the trick is to use the value of `calinga` but if it null because the key is not present then use the original value as the default: `item03 mapObject {($$):calinga[$] default $}`.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var calinga = {
    "Identification": "Identifikation",
    "Position and Contact": "Positions und Contacts",
    "Classification": "Classifikation",
    "Product Number": "Produkt Number",
    "Manufacturer": "Manufakturer",
    "Hardware Version": "Hware Vsion"
}
---
{
"editable": payload.editable,
"sections": payload.sections map(item01, index01)->{
    "title": calinga[item01.title],
    "content": item01.content map(item02)->(item02 map(item03)-> item03 mapObject {($$):calinga[$] default $})
    }
}
```